# nested routes in react does not render nested component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

App.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Redirect path="/" to="/dashboard/home" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Dashboard.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import MainDashboard from "./MainDashboard";

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Dashboard</div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/dashboard/home" Component={MainDashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

MainDashboard.tsx

```
import React from "react";

class MainDashboard extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        MainDashboard
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MainDashboard;
```

there r nested routes. the first one is the parent routes in App.tsx and then the nested routes is in Dashboard.tsx. 
the expected result is using /dashboard/home will render MainDashboard component. But it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create nested routes we need to use `match.url` and add some checks for what we want to render, `react-router-dom` will inject the `match` object as `this.props`.

we use `exact path={match.url}` as our "base route" and add our sub routes as `` path={`${match.url}/:sectionNAme`} ``

```
class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/dashboard/home" />} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => <div>Dashboard</div>} />
        <Route path={`${match.url}/home`} component={MainDashboard} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class MainDashboard extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        MainDashboard
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank u for you comment and actually I found my fault is I using Component in Route and the correct property is component.